# SQL: Difference Between RANK, DENSE_RANK and FIRST_VALUE

Tags: sql

I have the following table ("my_table").

```
    name score rank
1 Sophia    92    1
2   Emma    90    2
3    Mia    90    2
4  Lucas    88    4
5   John    85    5
6 Oliver    85    5
```

**I am trying to learn about the differences between the RANK, DENSE_RANK and FIRST_VALUE functions.**

I tried writing 3 queries with these functions:

```
# query 1: DENSE_RANK
SELECT 
    name, 
    score, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) as rank
FROM 
    my_data;

    name score rank
1 Sophia    92    1
2   Emma    90    2
3    Mia    90    2
4  Lucas    88    3
5   John    85    4
6 Oliver    85    4

# query 2: RANK
SELECT 
    name, 
    score, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) as rank
FROM 
    my_data;

   name score rank
1 Sophia    92    1
2   Emma    90    2
3    Mia    90    2
4  Lucas    88    4
5   John    85    5
6 Oliver    85    5

# query 3: first_value
SELECT 
    name, 
    score, 
    FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) as top_student
FROM 
    my_data;

    name score top_student
1 Sophia    92      Sophia
2   Emma    90      Sophia
3    Mia    90      Sophia
4  Lucas    88      Sophia
5   John    85      Sophia
6 Oliver    85      Sophia
```

Here is my understanding of the differences:

- DENSE_RANK assigns the same rank to ties
- RANK assigns different ranks to ties
- FIRST_VALUE simply selects the largest value (based on the partition clause) and repeats it throughout

**Is my understanding correct? In what kinds of problems is the FIRST_VALUE function useful?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

1. [Comparison of Rank and Dense Rank and Row Number](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/07/difference-between-rownumber-rank-and-denserank-sql-server.html#axzz8E3ZLvSes)
2. [Another more detailed article on Rank and Dense Rank](https://medium.com/@LoriLu/whats-the-difference-rank-vs-dense-rank-vs-row-number-3aca5ecfb928)

"As I told, the difference boils down to the fact when ties happen. In the case of the tie, ROW_NUMBER() will give unique row numbers, the rank will give the same rank, but the next different rank will not be in sequence, there will be a gap.

In the case of dense_rank, both rows in the tie will have the same rank and there will be no gap. The next different rank will be in sequence."